# Popup LOV with multiple values on Interactive Grid displays APEX 19.2

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 19.2 and I have an editable interactive grid with a POP LOV.
Multiple Values is checked
Display As is set to Modal Dialog

My List of Values is a SQL Query:

```
select name as d, id as r from table_x
```

I have two issues and I don't think I found a good question on SO that solves it:

1. Although the modal shows the human readable names to select from, once a record is Saved AND there's more than one value selected, the cell is displayed as ID1:ID2:ID3.... instead of NAME1:NAME2:NAME3...
2. IF the "name" is a string and not a number AND multiple values are selected THEN an "ORA-01722: invalid number" occurs

Note that in both cases, as long as only 1 value is selected there is no issues with saving.

I understand the storing the field with colons however I'm talking about the visible grid for the user. It should not show the user colon separated IDs after save but show the user list of users for example.

For example, here's a list of room numbers (100, 101...) and they correspond to IDs (3, 7 , 4)
[image]
[image]

I would suspect after I save, the table still shows 100, 101, .. NOT the IDs to the user.

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: If you store multiple values into an item in the IG using an multiselect POPUP lov, where is this information stored and how? Is this being splitted into mutliple records, one for each value? or is this stored as one single colon separated value?

Comment: @Giliam the values are stored in a single column in the database that's called rooms and it's a string. So I expect it to store "3:7:14"

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in an online environment, e.g. apex.oracle.com? It is hard to see he actual issue this way. I do think the Select Multiple Values from a POPUP LOV is being used the wrong way. But to give you an answer that leads to a working situation without seeing it is hard.

Comment: @Giliam ok here it is. Site = https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/multiselect-popup-lov/r/demo18/home  workspace = https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1  workspace = multiselect-popup-lov | username: demo | password: demo5678  you can see that in both columns, you can save if you choose 1 item but if you multiselect, then you can't save.

Comment: Now, I tried several things, but I do believe this is a bug. Seems like it has already been discussed in the Oracle Community as well https://community.oracle.com/message/15533322
Actually, when trying things I had come to the same conclusion as mentioned by Oleh Tyshchenko on the bottom of page 1.... The where clause doesn't work when having multiple values in the same column with a separator.

Comment: If you want to try it yourself. Enable debug, re-enter muliple values, save, check the debug logs. Somewhere at the bottom, just above "bulk fetching is NOT supported for this query" (isn't the issue) there is a query output which will show you the inline where clause which is incorrect, in case multiple values will be hold in the same column..